# How to start mongod and use the MongoDB database?

Tags: mongodb, installation, mongo-shell

I am trying to get `mongod` command working so that i can start a local MongoDB server.
I have installed everything seemingly without error and ran

```
"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin\mongo.exe"
```

Then closed it tried to run `mongod` and it said *mongod is not defined*. Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Comment: Did you install MondogDB as a Window service or did you install just the executable files?

Comment: Did you install MongoDB as a service? See the topic: [If you did not install MongoDB as a service](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#if-you-did-not-install-mongodb-as-a-windows-service).

Comment: Just the local server

Answer (score 0):

Ive seen this asked a few times. My issue was that i didnt set up the environment variables. When you download it run this in the terminal

```
"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin\mongo.exe"
```

Then try and run mongo --version

If it still doesnt work then go to the windows environment variables and add a path variable to "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin"
and then you should be able to run mongod --version